# How to restore the colors?

Tags: octopress

In order to text the colors I modified the file sass/custom/_colors.scss.
I added the following line:

```
header-bg: #ffffff;
```

I checked that the header color becomes white instead of black.

To restablish the situation,  I commented the line:

```
//header-bg: #ffffff;
```

BUT the header is always white !

Comment: Hit F5. The CSS is just chached.

Comment: No ! I tried this, I clean the cache also but no change !

Comment: Oh, just a guess. Can you take a look at the inspector? You can see what classes are being applied to the element to find out where the color is coming from.

Comment: <header role="banner">

Answer (score 0):

Try running `rake generate`, because I think the scss needs to be recomplied. You can also run `rake watch` so that any changes to the scss automatically cause regeneration in the future.